# How do I print the node title from the object?

Tags: 8, nodes

How do I print the title of a node entity? Printing the node object, I get this output.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
    [in_preview] => 
    [values] => Array
        (
            [vid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 2
                )

            [nid] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => 2
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => common
                )

            [title] => Array
                (
                    [x-default] => Terms of Use
                )
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Are you in a twig template rendering a node? If so:

`{{ label }}` or `{{ node.label }}`

Via code in PHP:

`$node->label();` via [`label()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Alabel/8.2.x) and/or also `$node->getTitle();` via [`getTitle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AgetTitle/8.2.x)

Comment: the above code was part configuration setting form . I got it work by using $node->get('title')->value .

Answer (score 0):

Tested: look for your node--.html.twig file, find the {{ content }}, then add this above or below, or anywhere you like to print the title: {{ node.label }}, it will show the current page/node title in your template, make sure you empty your cache to see the changes.